# How do I get an array of the followers of a user who has verified themselves? (Twitter API v1.1)

Tags: php, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

I am attempting to verify users through my app using TwitterOAuth.

I am to the point of, when they click the "use the app" button, it sends them to a twitter verification page, seen here:

http://puu.sh/3WRno.png

When they click "authorize app", it redirects them back to my site, with the following $_GET variables:

http://puu.sh/3WRoU.png

So I've verified them and have a `OAuth Token' and an`OAuth Verifier'.

I guess my question at this point is: how do I access the various elements of their twitter account (in this case: a list of their followers, and people they're following) with the OAuth variables that I have?

If somebody wouldn't mind pointing me in the right direction, I'd appreciate it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You now have a RequestToken and a Verifier. And with this two you can ask for an AccessToken. And with this AccessToken you can make all the API calls.

Hope that helps...

Surf here for helpful libraries: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries